# Show No Image against Specific Color if Image not there

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, color-swatches

i am using magento 1.9.2.3 version. Normally mangeto behave when user click on the different color or size in configurable product case system show the specific image against every color if specific color image is not upload than system display the default image.
But My client requirement is when user click on the different color or size in configurable product which image is not upload than system should be display 'No Image or Blank Image' instead of default image. Because customer confuse against colors.

Can someone know how can i do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hello I dont know the complete answer for this But I can help you somehow

this class `class Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Mediafallback` is responsible for media image for configurable product

Please debug in this file you will get the solution from this class only

Comment: can you please let me know the file path?

Comment: `app/code/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Mediafallback.php`

Comment: thanks. i just try to edit the code but its not effect on image.  //search by store-specific label and then default label if nothing is found
                $imageKey = array_search($map['label'], $imageHaystack);
                if ($imageKey === false) {
                  $imageKey = array_search($map['default_label'], $imageHaystack);   
      
                }